# Php Mail Going For spam

Tags: php

```
<?php if (isset ($_POST['submit'])&& ($_POST['submit']!='')){
      $to = 'manojpraharsha@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'Website Enquery Request';
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $headers = 'From: Timespaces <'.$to.'>' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$name.' <'.$email.'> ' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Return-Path:' .$to . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      $message .= '<html><body>';
      $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color:rgb(130,0,67);" cellpadding="10">';
      $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $email . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Subject:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['subject']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "</table>";
      $message .= "</body></html>";
      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
      }
      ?>
```

is there any mistakes in here where i tried all possibilities but also all mails goes to my spam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail() form sending to GMAIL spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188334/php-mail-form-sending-to-gmail-spam)

Comment: I used same code also, but same problem

Comment: This topic has been discussed on SO many times in many different ways.  Please continue to research and tell us all of the ways that you have tried to solve and which links your have found.

Comment: yea i have research all the codes and i have tried all of them including the code in the link you have suggested , but same issue its going to spam only

Comment: The error message in gmail is 'This message may not have been sent by: $email'  $email is the details entired by user

Comment: you're forging the sender, probably failing DKIM and SPF too.

Comment: also using "return path" in an email header

Comment: If you really have "researched all the codes" and "tried all possibilities", then clearly there is nothing new we can tell you. Please [edit] the question to include as much detail as you can. *What* have you researched? *What* possibilities have you tried? What is the *exact* result you've seen in GMail? Right now, there's a high chance of us telling you things you've already tried, because we're just playing guessing games, which is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PHP Mailer` with `SMTP` authentication, or send using dedicated IP  with popular( in active conversation ) sender email ID